# Restore-SPSite time scale to restore?

Tags: 2010, powershell, restore

I am trying to restore the main site at the root of our SharePoint server after an accidental deletion using the following code:

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity http://server -Path "B:\SharePoint\11-12-2012 21.00.26.bak" -Force
```

I have worked around the issue of the gradual site delete, but have been left with the PowerShell window unresponsive after confirming "Y"

The .bak is 37GB and connected to the server on an external disk

How long should the restore take and where can I check what is going on (and how if possible!)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a huge site. Depending on your hardware, that could take a few hours to run. I don't think you can check the status, just let it do its thing, and consider moving some of the webs into other site collections/content databases to minimize this downtime in the future.

Comment: I thought 37GB wasn't too bad considering some are over 100GB, still it took 3 hours.  That is disappointing if there is no way to monitor it.

Comment: Things get hairy up near 200GB per content DB, however I always aim to keep DBs as small as possible for effective DR